# ObjectAnimator Android is not working correctly on real device with API 19

Tags: java, android, animation, imageview, objectanimator

I am making a game for Android and I encountered a problem while working on my next update. Game is set to work from API 19 upwards. I am using ObjectAnimator class to animate little bouncing arrows pointing buttons in tutorial. Nothing fancy.

[Yellow arrow - Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsw3b.png)

Code:

```
 //Animate minestone clicker button arrow
            b1_animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button_minestone_pointer,"translationX",0,-100);
            b1_animator.setDuration(500);
            b1_animator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
            b1_animator.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            b1_animator.start();
```

Problem is, animations are smooth on ALL virtual devices provided by Android Studio (API 19 - API 27) and on all newer APIs, but on my phone (Sharp SH-01G), which is running Android 4.4, automatic scrolling or these arrows simply jump from one position to another creating blurred image. 
Did not have a chance to check it on another pre-API21 device yet.
Feeling like it does not respect the ".setDuration();" bit. Scrolls are jumping immediately to the desired position but not smoothly at all.

This is the scroller code:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofInt(scroller_clickers, "scrollX",  800).setDuration(777).start();
```

So the question is, what is causing such a behaviour? I tried using view.animate() instead too, but it didn't help either. Clue is, when I tried to lookup the "getAnimatedFraction();" value, emulators were showing various fractions - smooth transition between 0.0 and 1. My phone was always showing 0.0 or 1.0 in somehow random order (Stuffed this into a TextView and refreshed with a Runnable). Assigning "AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()" did not work either. I don't want to show a faulty game to the public :(

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting a `ObjectAnimator` logging errors in the logcat when your kitkat device is plugged in and on this screen?  Obviously `ObjectAnimator.ofInt` is between `int` (whole numbers), not like `ofFloat` - should the code be `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(scroller_clickers, "scrollX",  800).setDuration(777).start();` ?

Comment: Just checked. No, I am not getting any errors and changing to ofFloat did not help either. Game works just fine, apart from these animations. I have another animated coin manually which is put into an ImageSwitcher and just changes pictures with a high speed to create animation - that works fine. ObjectAnimator doesn't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fixed.
Turns out my phone had animations switched off from 1.0x to off in developer options which the ObjectAnimator class did not like. Works good now

Comment: Perfect answer. It was skipping all my delay and duration

Comment: OMG， I really don't know how to say that, the designer who turn off animation is really genius.